# Keyboard shortcut for killing application like google chrome when system hangs for Fedora?

Tags: fedora

I have Fedora 13 64 bit.
My system hangs sometimes like no response to keys or even mouse pointer is frozen due to a rogue application hijacking the whole system ( usually google chrome). What is the shortcut to kill the offending process? Ctrl Alt Backspace will kill the whole x-window session.

Also the shortcuts Ctrl Esc or Ctrl Alt Esc do not work on my fedora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can press CTRL+ALT+F1 and go in shell mode, from here you can check log file for view what is the cause of your problem, and you can also kill a process like chromo with :

killall google-chrome

then you can return in X server session with CTRL + ALT + F6 or F7 .

Alternatively you can press the SYSRQ combination(if you have enabled SYSRQ on your kernel) with :

- ALT + SYSRQ/PrintScr + b : for reboot
- ALT + SYSRQ/PrintScr + o : for shutdown
- ALT + SYSRQ/PrintScr + k : for for kill X Server